# According to my solution there should be more fixed points...

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

I have solved the following exercise:

> A group of order $55$ acts on a set of order $18$. Then there are at least $2$ fixed points.

But according to my solution, there should be at least 3 fixed points (I solved it via a form of Burnsides lemma and some basic number-theoretic reasoning). Is that true ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be an orbit of length 11, and one of length 5, so two fixed points are definitely a possibility.

For an example, take the cyclic group generated by the product of two disjoint cycles of length 5 and 11 in the symmetric group $S_{18}$.

Comment: But where is my error then ? My proof went as follows: We know that
$\left|X^{G}\right|=\left|X\right|-\sum_{x\in A}\frac{\left|G\right|}{\left|G_{x}\right|}$,
where $X^{G}$ denotes the set of all fixed points and $A$ is a system
of representatives of the orbits of those points that aren't fixed
points.

Then we have $\left|X^{G}\right|=18-55\sum\frac{1}{\left|G_{x}\right|}$.
Since $18-55\sum\frac{1}{\left|G_{x}\right|}\in\mathbb{N}$ the only
options for $\sum\frac{1}{\left|G_{x}\right|}\in\mathbb{Q}$ is to
be (...)

Comment: (...) of the form 
$$
\sum\frac{1}{\left|G_{x}\right|}=\frac{r}{11},\ r\in\left\{ 1,2,3\right\} \ \text{or}\ \sum\frac{1}{\left|G_{x}\right|}=\frac{1}{5},
$$
since otherwise either $55\sum\frac{1}{\left|G_{x}\right|}$ were
a purely rational number or $18-55\sum\frac{1}{\left|G_{x}\right|}$
were negative. Summarizing, for the four possible cases above we have
$\left|X^{G}\right|\in\left\{ 13,8,3,7\right\} $.

Comment: @user47574 16/55=1/11+1/5.

Comment: In the example I gave above, you equality reads $2 = 55 - 55/5 - 55/11$.

Comment: @peoplepower or (Andreas Caranti) Ah, so this is the only case I forgot, right ? (i.e. to fix my proof, there aren't any other cases I have to consider, for which the equation also gives $2$?)